# How do i use native flash TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM with non-interactiveObject

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, gesture

Is there any way to use the native flash TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM with non-"flash InteractiveObject"? For example, is there any way to add this event to stage? I need to zoom the world that was build by Axel Game Library, but it doesn't support this kind of events. Should i use some invisible sprite to put all axgl world to it? Or is there any way to write my own gesture_zoom event that would apply to the stage?
I would like to use Ax.zoom axgl property to zoom the world by this event, so i need to only catch it.

Answer (score 0):

If the non interactive object is a    DisplayObject, you could consider add it as a child of an    InteractiveObject.  You can then capture guesture event from the InteractiveObject, and apply it to your target object.

If the non interactive object is not a   DisplayObject, you can create an interactive object that represents the display region of your non interactive object, then translate any of the guesture event from the InteractiveObject to your target object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how do i always put interactive object on the top of all other objects while using stage3d?

Answer (score 0):

Oh that's kinda late answer, but still... Try to use my gesture recognition library [Gestouch](https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch) — it can work with non-"flash InteractiveObject" and can do bunch of other things.